# I am trying to make a Spring MVC application but the application refuses to start Tomcat Throws errors

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat7, java-6

Tomcat 7  Throws an error saying the application requires more time to start but even if i increase the timeout to 600 sec the same error comes up , how can i run the application .
I am loading all the jars from https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/spring/

I am using jdk 1.6

Version 4.2.5 But still error .
Please help how can i run my application.

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKfLW.png)

Comment: can you give us the error u r getting?

Comment: I have added the error image to the question , even if the increase the timeout to 600 sec the same error pops up 

Localhost was unable to start within 600 sec it requires more time to start

Comment: OK, now can you share the stack trace please.

Answer (score 0):

- Solution : remove all project from Tomcat server, then restart tomcat again.
- Method :
  Window tab -> show view -> select server --> then right click server -> add and remove --> remove all configured --> finish --> restart server, may it help you.

Comment: Already tried this not helping , this is the only project i am running but it is not working after clean server setup too

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat 7 normally starts within a few seconds. It sounds like you have one of these problems:

1. Something is going drastically wrong - check all logs in the /logs directory there may be clues in there.
2. Something in the static initialisation code of one of your classes is taking forever. Put breakpoints in any static initialization code and see if they are reached, and that control is returned to Tomcat in a timely fashion.
3. Something in the static initialisation code of another deployed application is taking forever. Undeploy all other apps (if there are any) and try again.

Also, try undeploying your application. Does Tomcat start normally now? This will sort out whether the problem is the Tomcat installation or your application.

My guess (and it is a guess) is that you are trying to open a mis-configured remote resource like a database, web service or JMS queue. Web services are often the culprit, as the JAXWS default is to have an infinite timeout. You need to do extra work to implement timeouts.